# Why UTC offset is the same when time zone was changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Here's the code I use:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
TimeSpan offset = zone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
```

My time zone is +3 and offset is initally 3 hours, which is fine. But, when I change time zone through the Windows 7 control panel to +6, the offset is still 3. I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you changing the time zone on server? Does the time zone change take effect?

Comment: IIS is on my locale machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` reads a lazy initialized static field, it's **assigned once** at first access and it will not be destroyed/recreated if you change your system settings. From disassembled source code:

```
public static TimeZone CurrentTimeZone {
    get {
        if (currentTimeZone != null)
            return currentTimeZone;

        lock (InternalSyncObject) {
            if (TimeZone.currentTimeZone == null)
                TimeZone.currentTimeZone = new CurrentSystemTimeZone();

            return TimeZone.currentTimeZone;
        }
    }
}
```

To "reset" it you have to unload AppDomain or handle that event by yourself and call `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` method (tnx tesicg, my original *suggestion* is deleted code below).

<del>var field = typeof(TimeZone).GetField("curretTimeZone",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    field.SetValue(null, null);

Resetting `currentTimeZone` to null it'll force `CurrentTimeZone` to re-create it when needed. Please note here we rely on an small implementation detail (field name and behavior) so you have to think if you really need it.</del>

Will your server move across time zones? If not then **don't worry** about it...

Comment: I've also noticed the same code works fine in ordinary console application. But, not in my ASP.NET application.

Comment: @tesicg it works **only** if you re-run your console application. If you read it, wait for a keypress, change settings, press a key and re-read then you'll obviously get same value (because it's now it's stored in a static field initialized only first time you read it).In case of ASP.NET it won't be re-read until process will be restarted (or when IIS decide to serve a request inside another process).

Comment: You're right. In the meantime, I've discovered that this works as well:

TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
TimeZoneInfo local = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
TimeSpan offset = local.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);

Comment: @tesicg I missed that method! Yes, much better than tricky reflection (if really needed).